# How to import Swagger APIs into Postman?

Tags: swagger, postman

Recently I wrote restful APIs with *SpringMvc* and swagger-ui(v2). I noticed the Import function in Postman:

[image]

So my question is how to create the file which Postman needed?

I am not familiar with Swagger.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I work on PHP and have used Swagger 2.0 to document the APIs. 
The Swagger Document is created on the fly (at least that is what I use in PHP). The document is generated in the JSON format.

Sample document

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
    "title": "Company Admin Panel",
        "description": "Converting the Magento code into core PHP and RESTful APIs for increasing the performance of the website.",
        "contact": {
        "email": "jaydeep1012@gmail.com"
        },
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "host": "localhost/cv_admin/api",
    "schemes": [
    "http"
],
    "paths": {
    "/getCustomerByEmail.php": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "List the details of customer by the email.",
                "consumes": [
                "string",
                "application/json",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],
                "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "email",
                        "in": "body",
                        "description": "Customer email to ge the data",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "abc": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "inner_abc": {
                                                "type": "number",
                                                    "default": 1,
                                                    "example": 123
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "xyz": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                            "default": "xyz default value",
                                            "example": "xyz example value"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Details of the customer"
                    },
                    "400": {
                    "description": "Email required"
                    },
                    "404": {
                    "description": "Customer does not exist"
                    },
                    "default": {
                    "description": "an \"unexpected\" error"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/getCustomerById.php": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "List the details of customer by the ID",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "Customer ID to get the data",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Details of the customer"
                    },
                    "400": {
                    "description": "ID required"
                    },
                    "404": {
                    "description": "Customer does not exist"
                    },
                    "default": {
                    "description": "an \"unexpected\" error"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/getShipmentById.php": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "List the details of shipment by the ID",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "Shipment ID to get the data",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Details of the shipment"
                    },
                    "404": {
                    "description": "Shipment does not exist"
                    },
                    "400": {
                    "description": "ID required"
                    },
                    "default": {
                    "description": "an \"unexpected\" error"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {

    }
}
```

This can be imported into Postman as follow.

1. Click on the '**Import**' button in the top left corner of Postman UI.
2. You will see multiple options to import the API doc. Click on the '**Paste Raw Text**'.
3. Paste the JSON format in the text area and click import.
4. You will see all your APIs as '**Postman Collection**' and can use it from the Postman.

[image: Importing the JSON into Postman]

[image: Imported APIs]

You can also use 'Import From Link'. Here paste the URL which generates the JSON format of the APIs from the Swagger or any other API Document tool.

This is my Document (JSON) generation file. It's in PHP. I have no idea of JAVA along with Swagger.

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$swagger = \Swagger\scan('path_of_the_directory_to_scan');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $swagger;
```

Comment: thanks, but now the problem is how could I export the file from swagger-ui?And the link is useless.

Comment: @DemonColdmist I have added the code to generate the API. Basically, it scans the entire directory, checks the annotations and makes the JSON/YAML output. Sorry, but I haven't used Swagger with JAVA.

Comment: thanks, if it could be export in PHP, so do Java. I will translate it into Java.

Comment: In a java app using the springfox-swagger2 dependency, you can get the JSON to import in Postman as described in this answer by opening a browser and heading to http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Comment: @JDpawar Thanks, the import succeed, but it's not generating any 'body' info in postman for any POST API. any ideas?

Answer (score 103):

With .Net Core it is now very easy:

1. You go and find JSON URL on your swagger page:

[image]

2. Click that link and copy the URL
3. Now go to Postman and click Import:

[image]

4. Select what you need and you end up with a nice collection of endpoints:

[image]

Comment: In case you don't see the JSON URL on your swagger page, you can inspect (`F12`) and go to the network tab then reload the page. You should see a request called `swagger`, which contains the url: https://i.imgur.com/bM1Fv9C.png
In case the request is named something other than `swagger` you can find it by looking for `{swagger: "2.0",` in the preview tab: https://i.imgur.com/40DTShz.png

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is correct but I will rewrite complete steps for `java`.

I am currently using `Swagger V2` with `Spring Boot 2` and it's straightforward 3 step process.

**Step 1:** Add required dependencies in `pom.xml` file. The second dependency is optional use it only if you need `Swagger UI`.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Step 2:** Add configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

     public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact("Usama Amjad", "https://stackoverflow.com/users/4704510/usamaamjad", "hello@email.com");
      public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = new ApiInfo("Article API", "Article API documentation sample", "1.0", "urn:tos",
              DEFAULT_CONTACT, "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", new ArrayList<VendorExtension>());

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Set<String> producesAndConsumes = new HashSet<>();
        producesAndConsumes.add("application/json");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                .produces(producesAndConsumes)
                .consumes(producesAndConsumes);

    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Setup complete and now you need to document APIs in `controllers`

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a list Articles for a given Author", response = Article.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found") })
    @GetMapping(path = "/articles/users/{userId}")
    public List<Article> getArticlesByUser() {
       // Do your code
    }
```

**Usage:**

You can access your Documentation from `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` just copy it and paste in Postman to import collection.

[image]

**Optional Swagger UI:** You can also use standalone UI without any other rest client via `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` and it's pretty good, you can host your documentation without any hassle.

[image]

Comment: Error while importing: Error while importing Swagger 2.0: (Patchable) parameter.type is mandatory for non-body parameters

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me from the Swagger editor interface:

## Method 1

### Copy the `YAML` file contents into the `Raw Text` area:

[image]

## Method 2 (more steps)

### Step 1: Export the file as JSON

[image]

### Step 2: Import the `JSON` file with Postman "Import"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Recommend you to read this answer**

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/51072071/4712855**

Refer to the  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39072519  answer, and then partially delete the returned content. Finally, it is found that swagger lacks some configuration and postmat cannot be imported.

You need to add the following configuration in swagger

```
@Bean
public Docket api(SwaggerProperties swaggerProperties) {
 swaggerProperties.setTitle("my-project");
 swaggerProperties.setDescription("my project");
 swaggerProperties.setVersion("v1");
 swaggerProperties.getContact().setUrl("http");
 //I overlooked other configurations. Note that my swagger configuration lacks these.
}
```

In short, the attributes in the ApiInfoBuilder class are assigned values as much as possible

spring-boot version:2.3.10.RELEASE
springfox-swagger version: 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do that: Postman -> Import -> Link -> `{root_url}/v2/api-docs`

Answer (score -1):

- Click on the orange button ("choose files")
- Browse to the Swagger doc (swagger.yaml)
- After selecting the file, a new collection gets created in POSTMAN. It will contain folders based on your endpoints.

You can also get some sample swagger files online to verify this(if you have errors in your swagger doc).

Comment: could you show me the way how to export the swagger.yaml?I am using swagger-ui in SpringMvc.

Comment: where do you want to export swagger from? are you already using swagger to author your YAML?

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem strapi side.
I just get the json from network.

### Get Swagger JSON from Network

[image]

Get this json and save it as file.

[image]

Import you saved json file before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click number 1 then 2. You will see the entire api in postman.
[image]

Comment: Is this a way to fix the problem? By pulling the JSON out of the browser cache and import?

Comment: As i shared. It worked for me.

Comment: I'd recommend editing out "I have same problem strapi side" since it suggests there may not be a solution/answer in this post.

Comment: You are right until google shows me first when i wrote this things. Your concern is not make better this answer/question. You may right but worked solution has better chance.

Comment: This is still working though. It is not depends on strapi side or not. I came again then solve my problem. Thanks to me.