# Unable to import swagger JSON or YAML into Postman

Tags: json, swagger, postman, dropwizard, swagger-2.0

**Problem**

Unable to convert **swagger 2.0** into a format which is being affected by Postman import functionality

Generated via `/swagger.json|yaml`

Swagger endpoint exposed via dropwizard jetty using swagger

- ***swagger-core: 1.5.17***
- swagger-jaxrs: 1.5.17
- swagger-jersey2-jaxrs: 1.5.17
- swagger-models: 1.5.17

**Attempts**

Tried manually importing the JSON or YAML versions via the import screen

- import file
- import from link
- paste raw text

Tried converting to different formats using: [api-spec-converter](https://github.com/LucyBot-Inc/api-spec-converter) and [swagger2-postman-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger2-postman-generator)

**Result**

Error on import: `Must contain an info object`

**Question**

Has anyone managed to get around this issue allowing the import

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swagger 2.0 the info field is mandatory. Just add the following to your YAML root:

```
info:
  title: 'EmptyTitle'
  description: 'EmptyDescription'
  version: 0.1.0
```

Or like this if you have it in JSON format (in the root too):

```
"info": {
  "title": "EmptyTitle",
  "description": "EmptyDescription",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: thank you, after add it to raw json script, it work well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting to Postman v2?

The `swagger2-postman-generator` you tried converts Swagger v2 to Postman v1. This one converts Swagger v2 to Postman v2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger2-postman2-converter as used in [this tutorial](http://blog.getpostman.com/2018/03/02/sync-your-specs/).

Comment: It is already in version 2 format, as mentioned in my posting... BBerastegui has found the trick (y)

Answer (score 0):

My setup: Spring boot generated swagger-ui, which gives me the raw open-api documentation.

In my case

```
"info": {
  "title": "EmptyTitle"
}
```

was already available in the json which spring-boot open api generated for me, but was missing the other two fields which @BBerastegui mentions in his answer:

```
  "description": "EmptyDescription",
  "version": "0.1.0"
```

I added them, and the esult looks like

so that the rsult looks like this, which works:

```
"info": {
  "title": "EmptyTitle",
  "description": "EmptyDescription",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```