# NestJs Swagger for Postman

Tags: swagger, postman, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

Is there a way to import the generated swagger.json to Postman as an collection ?

I tried to import it but the Endpoints are not shown in Postman ?

I am using NestJs and Swagger + Postman

Comment: Can you share the swagger yaml file?

Comment: i don't use an yaml file to generate the swagger api. I specified it in the main.ts

Comment: Can you share the generated json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fastify-swagger` to export your swagger data using it in Postman after it.

> To generate and download a Swagger JSON file, navigate to http://localhost:3000/api-json (swagger-ui-express) or http://localhost:3000/api/json (fastify-swagger) in your browser (assuming that your Swagger documentation is available under http://localhost:3000/api).

More informations about openApi with NestJS is available [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction)

Comment: thanks for your message. Currently I am trying to import the swagger-ui-express version. After the import from api/json in postman nothing is shown there.  There are also some errors in the json file:
 "securitySchemes": {
      "bearer": {
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT",
        "type": "http",
        "in": "header"
      }

Invalid Properties

Comment: The same import is working in Insomnia but not in Postman

Comment: Try to import the exported data from Swagger to Insomnia and to export the Insomnia data to Postman, could work as documented [here](https://community.postman.com/t/importing-collection-from-insomnia-v4-as-json-format/9915)

Answer (score 8):

When setting up your swagger in main.ts (see documentation here: [NestJs Swagger Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction)) you can add `.setExternalDoc('Postman Collection', '/your-api-docs-url-with-the-word-json-at-the-end')`. That gives you a link right at the top of your file so you can click to get the importable JSON.

Here's an example of mine:

```
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(
    app,
    new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle('Nest Api')
      .setDescription('MyNestApiDescription')
      .setVersion('1.0')
      .addBearerAuth()
      .setExternalDoc('Postman Collection', '/docs-json')
      .build(),
  );
  SwaggerModule.setup('/docs', app, document);
```

as you can see my API documentation is located at `'/docs'` so my json url is simply `'/docs-json'`.

[image: Image of Postman Collection Link]

See this stackoverflow post for info on how to import it into Postman: [Postman JSON Docs Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072216/how-to-import-swagger-apis-into-postman)